# Stash what I am currently working on, and revert back to the last commit

Tags: git

My web application was working fine at my last commit, i.e.:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'asdf'
```

I don't want to throw away what I have now, is it possible to stash what I have now, revert back to the last commit?

And how can I get what I stashed back once I figure out what happened?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for any non-committed content, `git stash` should be enough (and `git stash pop` to restore)

Should you have made one more commit, you could name that branch with a `git branch tmp`, and then `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to reset the current branch HEAD.

Comment: what do you mean if I made more than one commit, how can I create a branch? a branch of a previous commit you mean? that's a cool idea.

Comment: @Blankman: yes, typo there. And you can "create" a branch by giving another name to your current branch HEAD. And then reset your current branch HEAD to a previous commit.